# what does 'in' mean in javascript if statement

Tags: javascript

Hi i'm following a tutorial learning to use javascript.

```
function move(keyclick) {
if(40 in keyclick) {}
playerMove.x++;
render(); }
```

What does the 'in' word mean? I understand what the function is doing, but why not just use == 
?

Thanks

Comment: keyclick would be an array, and `in` is basically doing a pseudo-code equivalent of `if (keyclick[40] exists)`.

Comment: in is used to iteration through properties of an object.

Comment: [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) says it all. First match goggleing `js in`

Comment: If you think [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and `==` are interchangeable here, you don't understand what the function is doing at all.

Comment: Off Topic: @Night.owl, `40 in keyclick` implies that the code managing keyclick is adding and deleting properties, wich is not good. Since the key is numeric I assume that `keyclick` is an Array? It would be be better to initialize this Array with 256 `false`s and then toggling the particular value, instead of adding and deleting properties, and checking them with `in`.

Answer (score 1):

[The `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is `true` if the string on the LHS is the name of a property that exists on the object on the RHS.

`==` tests if a value matches another value, which is entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object (cited from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).